# Best way to store multiple type of data

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, redis, database

I'm about to design a database for a project I'm working to. I need to store multiple type of data, like Videos , Photos , text , audio. I've to store them and through php  I have to query them frequently. This project I'm working on is a Social Network and I need to connect users through notification and messages. 
Here is the question : Is more helpfull to use NoSQL DB's to store data and for the notification system ( Like MongoDB and Redis ) or MySQL can help me as well with this kind of systems? 
Sorry for my english , but technical stuff are so hard to explain for a english beginner like me. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with SQL techs, i.e. MySQL is that normally you have to place that binary text within a BLOB at which point you are already doing it wrong.

Another thing to consider is that file system access will always be faster than database access whether it is MongoDB or SQL, however, database storage does have some advantages. Eventually on your site (if it were to get slightly popular) you will find you need a CDN. These sorts of distribution networks can be costly however with something like MongoDB you can just spin up replicas of the data in other regions and have the binary data replicate as it is needed (maybe even TTL'd just like a CDN).

So this is one area to consider, that the file system is not most of the time, the right answer for a high load site like a social network. However even facebook themselves are not immune to having to serve directly from a file system, as they state ( https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=2406207130 , considering this post is 5 years old but I doubt much has changed on this front):

> We have also developed our own specialized web servers that are tuned to serve files with as few disk reads as possible. Even with thousands of hard drive spindles, I/O (input/output) is still a concern because our traffic is so high. Our squid caches help reduce the load, but squid isn't nearly fast or efficient enough for our purposes, so we're writing our own web accelerator too.

However they do have an extremely large infrastructure and most likely you should more like consider whether you use database storage or a CDN.

I would personally say you should probably do some research into content distribution networks and how other sites serve their images. You can find information all over Google. You can search specifically for Facebook, who until recently, were using Akamai for their CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can go either way. But storing binary data in a db is usually not the most efficient path. You are better off storing that in the filesystem and put the paths in the DB.